# How to deploy image files along with Windows Forms through ClickOnce in C#?

Tags: winforms, clickonce, .net-4.5, localdb

I have a winform [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.5 and [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) ([Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012)). It uses localDb to set a database in each user's machine through [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).
I have more than 100,000 images which are not stored in the database, and I want to deploy them along with my application. In this situation in which these image files are static and supposed to be loaded in a PictureBox, what is the best practice?

Setting files 'Build Action' to "content" and 'Copy to output' to "copy always" are a really time-consuming job. Should I mark them as 'Data' File or copy them in the application folder?

How should I do it?

Comment: Can you not select all files at once and select "Copy Always"? Also check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fehc36e.aspx

Comment: It can be. But it really a time and resource consuming job. For 16,000 files it takes more than 3 hours. I don't want to do that. And what If there is update to my program, A new image which should be installed on the user's machine in an update action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my company, Red Sky Software, makes a product called ClickOnceMore that may work for you here.

It's an alternative tool to VS for building ClickOnce manifests. It allows you to use inclusion rules to include all files in a directory without having to select each one individually.

I have to admit, it has not been tested with 100,000 files so I don't know what performance will be like, but it would be worth a try. You can download a free trial from [ClickOnceMore.net](http://www.clickoncemore.net).

Comment: Thank you. But I want to handle it with clickonce.